# Count the maximum number of 0s between two 1s in list python

Tags: python, list, binary

I want to count the 0s between two 1s from a list.
For example:

`l = [0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0]`

I want the output to be `[4,2,1]`. How can I do that in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### My one-liner

Just for fun (not that I encourage doing so in real project), here is a one liner (but a big line), using almost all iterators in `itertools` (well, not nearly, in reality. There are really lot of them)

```py
(y for (x,y),(z,t) in itertools.pairwise(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x[0]==0, ((x,sum(1 for _ in y)) for x,y in itertools.groupby(l)))) if x==0)
```

It's an iterator, and nowhere in the process do I build any list. So it would work f l was itself an iterator giving billions of 1 and 0, without using any memory

### Explanation

```
itertools.groupby(l)
```

is an iterator giving subiterators for each new value of l.
So

```
for v,it in itertools.groupby(l):
    for x in it:
        print(x)
```

Just prints all elements of l. But with 9 iterations `for x in it`, one in which x is 1 time 0, then one in which x is 1 time 1, then one in which x is 4 times 0, then etc.

If `y` is an iterator, then `sum(1 for _ in y)` is the number of iterations.

So

```py
((x,sum(1 for _ in y)) for x,y in itertools.groupby(l))
```

iterates pairs `(value0or1, numberOfSuchInGroup)`, with alternating `value0or1`

For example

```py
list((x,sum(1 for _ in y)) for x,y in itertools.groupby(l))
```

here is

```
[(0, 1), (1, 1), (0, 4), (1, 3), (0, 2), (1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 1)]
```

If want to drop the first pair, at least if it is a group of 0, since leading 0 does not count. Plus, I want to play with another iterator, which is `dropwhile`. So

```py
itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x[0]==0, ((x,sum(1 for _ in y)) for x,y in itertools.groupby(l)))
```

is the same iterator as before. But without the first pair if it is group of 0

```py
list(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x[0]==0, ((x,sum(1 for _ in y)) for x,y in itertools.groupby(l))))
```

is

```
[(1, 1), (0, 4), (1, 3), (0, 2), (1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 1)]
```

I also want do drop the last pair (at least if it is a group of 0, but it doesn't hurt if I drop it also if it is a group of 1). And I haven't played with `pairwise` yet. Which iterates through pairs of subsequent elemnents

```py
list(itertools.pairwise(range(5)))
```

is

```
((0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4))
```

for example

Here, I use it for a very silly reason: just to drop the last item, since of course, there is one less item in pairwise iteration. In my last example, we have 4 items

```py
list(x for x,y in itertools.pairwise(range(5)))
```

is

```
[0,1,2,3]
```

So, strange usage of `pairwise`, but it drops the last iteration used that way.

So in our case

```py
((x,y) for (x,y),(z,t) in itertools.pairwise(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x[0]==0, ((x,sum(1 for _ in y)) for x,y in itertools.groupby(l)))))
```

is the same iterator as before, but without the last pair

```py
list((x,y) for (x,y),(z,t) in itertools.pairwise(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x[0]==0, ((x,sum(1 for _ in y)) for x,y in itertools.groupby(l)))))
```

is

```
[(1, 1), (0, 4), (1, 3), (0, 2), (1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 2)]
```

Now that we have only groups of 0 that are valid, we can filter out the 1s

```py
list((x,y) for (x,y),(z,t) in itertools.pairwise(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x[0]==0, ((x,sum(1 for _ in y)) for x,y in itertools.groupby(l)))) if x==0)
```

is

```
[(0, 4), (0, 2), (0, 1)]
```

Plus, we don't need the 0s because at this stage they are all 0 anyway.
So, keep just `y` not `(x,y)`

```py
list(y for (x,y),(z,t) in itertools.pairwise(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x[0]==0, ((x,sum(1 for _ in y)) for x,y in itertools.groupby(l)))) if x==0)
```

Is

```
[4,2,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different way using `itertools.groupby` - using the fact that any entries beyond the first and last `1` is irrelevant to us

```py
from itertools import groupby

first_one = l.index(1) # index of the first "1"
last_one = len(l) - l[::-1].index(1) - 1 # index of the last "1"
out = [len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(l[first_one:last_one], key=lambda x: x == 0) if k]
```

**Output**

```
[4, 2, 1]
```

Comment: That answer is the only one that could run with low memory on a billion element list (well, with my "Rube Goldberg" version, which is quite similar, except that I suffered way more to remove 1st and last element). Because it is just an iterator, not a list. Or at least, it could be, just replacing the outer brackets by parenthesis in the last line. Of course, that advantage is void if what we need at the end is to build a list from an iterator. But there are many situation where we don't. For example if we just want to compute longest sequence, or number of length-3 sequences...

Comment: I am not sure how memory efficient `l[::-1]` method is at finding the last index in a billion element list though :)

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right. I missed that part. Especially if `l` is an iterator itself. Then, it that case, we are stuck with my Rube machine. Which may not be that bad after all :D

Answer (score 0):

One option using [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas):

```
l = [0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0]

s = pd.Series(l)

out = (s[s.eq(0)&s.cummax()&s.loc[::-1].cummax()]
       .rsub(1).groupby(s.ne(0).cumsum()).sum()
       .tolist()
      )
```

With pure python and `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

l = [0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0]

out = []
start = False
for k, g in groupby(l):
    if k == 1:
        if start:
            out.append(count)
        start = True
    else:
        count = len(list(g))
```

output: `[4, 2, 1]`

Answer (score 0):

How about this, explanation is all in the code:

```py
l = [0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0]
output = []

for i in range(len(l)): #this goes through every index in l (1,2,3,...15, 16)
  if l[i] == 1: #if in the list at the current index is a 1 it
    zeros = 0 #sets zeros to 0
    while l[i+1+zeros] == 0: #and starts a while loop as long as the current index+1+'the amount of zeros after the last number 1' is a zero. (so it stops when it reaches another 1)
      zeros += 1 # because the while loop still runs it adds another 0
      if i+1+zeros == len(l): #the current index + 1 + 'the amount of zeros' = the length of our list
        zeros = 0 # it sets zeros back to 0 so the program doesn't add them to the output (else the output would be [4, 2, 1, 1])
        break #breaks out of the loop
    if zeros > 0: #if the zeros counted between two 1s are more then 0:
      output.append(zeros) # it adds them to our final output
    
print(output) #prints [4, 2, 1] to the terminal
```

Comment: Why `zeros = 0.` not `zeros = 0`? It makes it float. And then the algorithm breaks because indices cannot be floats.

Comment: sorry, you are right. It was a syntax error I made when copying, i'll change it.

Answer (score 0):

An old-school answer.

```py
def count(l: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    res = []
    counter = 0
    lastx = l[0]
    for x in l[1:]:
        rising = (x-lastx) > 0
        if rising and counter != 0:
            res.append(counter)
        counter = counter+1 if x==0 else 0
        lastx = x
    return res

count([0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0])  # [4, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple version of the code:

```
newstr=[0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0]
output=[]
count=0

#This removes all preceding zeroes so that the first element is always 1
while newstr[0]==0:
    if newstr[0]==0:
        newstr=newstr[1::]

#This counts the number of zeroes
for k in newstr:
    if k==1:
        if count!=0:    #Ignoring count if it is zero
            output.append(count)
        count=0
    if k==0:
        count+=1
print(output)
#Output is [4,2,1]
```

**While Loop** -  checks if first element is 0
If the first element is 0, The list is sliced from 2nd element to the end

So now we have a list with first element as 1

**For Loop** - Counts the number of zeroes
If the element is 0 , then count+=1
If the element is 1, then the count is appended to the output list and count is reset to 0 again

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: I have edited the answer. Check it for explanation